# Induction proof with numerator and denominator

Tags: inequality, induction

I am stuck during the induction process where everything will fall into place if I show:
$\frac{x+1}{1-mx} \leq \frac{1}{1 - (m+1)x}$ for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and any $x \in (0, \frac{1}{m+1})$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since both denominators are positive, you can muliply the inequality with $(1-mx)(1-(m+1)x)$ to get rid of the fractions.

Comment: But we lose information if we do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given inequality is equivalent to

$$1-(m+1)x+x-(m+1)x^2\le 1-mx$$

cancelling out $1-mx$, we get

$$-(m+1)x^2\le 0,$$ which is clearly true.

Comment: I do not agree with that because that is true for any $x$. The fact that you multiplied to get rid of denominator means we already lost the information that $x \in (0, \frac{1}{m+1}$.

Comment: For the x in the given interval, we do not lose information because the denominators are positive.

Comment: Well, set $m = 1$ and therefore $x \in (0, \frac{1}{2}$. Then the equation is not even defined but your equation still holds true.

Comment: The interval is open on both sides, so $x<\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I see. Thanks peter.